# Is there a way to add a second graphql endpoint in a spring-graphql project?

Tags: spring-graphql

The background is that one endpoint is only intended for use within a data center and the other is intended to be publicly accessible.

I read the documentation, but this topic is never mentioned.

Comment: so this probably means two different schemas, different security configuration, different schema compatibility guarantees to clients, etc. Why not make those two different applications?

Comment: This is a possibility that I actually wanted to avoid, because the two endpoints are supposed to share a part of the data model. If split into two applications, this would mean that any change to the shared data model in one application would also have to be made in the other application.
Since the second endpoint should only provide very few queries and mutations, it would also be possible to simply use an ordinary RestController. However, this mixture again increases the applications complexity.
Conclusion: Two applications are probably the simplest way, even with a duplicate data model.

Answer (score 1):

It is doable - though a little bit hack imho. I have the issue, that I want to expose a anon accessible GraphQL endpoint next to an authenticating one. For having an easy Spring Security setup, two endpoints (in my case `/graphql` and `/anon/graphql`) should be provided. I solved it this way:

```java
package com.xyz.something;

import graphql.execution.instrumentation.Instrumentation;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.reactive.GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.ExecutionGraphQlService;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.BatchLoaderRegistry;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultExecutionGraphQlService;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.RuntimeWiringConfigurer;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.SubscriptionExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlHandler;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlInterceptor;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.webflux.GraphQlHttpHandler;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicate;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.accept;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.contentType;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ysura.webApi", "com.ysura.crm.datascope.application"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {GraphQLConfiguration.AnonGraphQlProperties.class})
public class GraphQLConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GraphQLConfiguration.class);

    /**
     * GraphQL source for the auth part of the API (has to be created manually due to the {@link ConditionalOnMissingBean} 
     * annotation in {@link GraphQlAutoConfiguration}).
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public GraphQlSource authGraphQlSource(
            final ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory,
            final ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver,
            final GraphQlProperties properties,
            final ObjectProvider<DataFetcherExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers,
            final ObjectProvider<SubscriptionExceptionResolver> subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
            final ObjectProvider<Instrumentation> instrumentations,
            final ObjectProvider<RuntimeWiringConfigurer> wiringConfigurers,
            final ObjectProvider<GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer> sourceCustomizers
    ) {
        return new GraphQlAutoConfiguration(listableBeanFactory).graphQlSource(
                resourcePatternResolver,
                properties,
                exceptionResolvers,
                subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
                instrumentations,
                wiringConfigurers,
                sourceCustomizers
        );
    }

    /**
     * GraphQL source for the anon part of the API (has to be created manually as this is the secondary GraphQL endpoint).
     */
    @Bean
    public GraphQlSource anonGraphQlSource(
            final ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory,
            final ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver,
            final GraphQLConfiguration.AnonGraphQlProperties properties,
            final ObjectProvider<DataFetcherExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers,
            final ObjectProvider<SubscriptionExceptionResolver> subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
            final ObjectProvider<Instrumentation> instrumentations,
            final ObjectProvider<RuntimeWiringConfigurer> wiringConfigurers,
            final ObjectProvider<GraphQlSourceBuilderCustomizer> sourceCustomizers
    ) {
        return new GraphQlAutoConfiguration(listableBeanFactory).graphQlSource(
                resourcePatternResolver,
                properties.getGraphql(),
                exceptionResolvers,
                subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
                instrumentations,
                wiringConfigurers,
                sourceCustomizers
        );
    }

    /**
     * Router to the anon part of the API (has to be created manually as this is the secondary GraphQL endpoint). The router
     * to the auth API is auto created in {@link GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration}.
     */
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> anonGraphQlRouterFunction(
            @Qualifier("anonGraphQlHttpHandler") final GraphQlHttpHandler httpHandler,
            @Qualifier("anonGraphQlSource") final GraphQlSource graphQlSource,
            final AnonGraphQlProperties properties
    ) {
        return new GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration().graphQlRouterFunction(
                httpHandler,
                graphQlSource,
                properties.getGraphql()
        );
    }

    /**
     * GraphQL HTTP handler for the auth part of the API (has to be created manually due to the {@link ConditionalOnMissingBean}
     * annotation in {@link GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration}).
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public GraphQlHttpHandler authGraphQlHttpHandler(@Qualifier("authWebGraphQlHandler") final WebGraphQlHandler webGraphQlHandler) {
        return new GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration().graphQlHttpHandler(webGraphQlHandler);
    }

    /**
     * GraphQL HTTP handler for the anon part of the API (has to be created manually as this is the secondary GraphQL endpoint).
     */
    @Bean
    public GraphQlHttpHandler anonGraphQlHttpHandler(@Qualifier("anonWebGraphQlHandler") final WebGraphQlHandler webGraphQlHandler) {
        return new GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration().graphQlHttpHandler(webGraphQlHandler);
    }

    /**
     * Web GraphQL handler for the auth part of the API (has to be created manually due to the {@link ConditionalOnMissingBean}
     * annotation in {@link GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration}).
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public WebGraphQlHandler authWebGraphQlHandler(
            @Qualifier("authExecutionGraphQlService") final ExecutionGraphQlService service,
            final ObjectProvider<WebGraphQlInterceptor> interceptorsProvider
    ) {
        return new GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration().webGraphQlHandler(service, interceptorsProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Web GraphQL handler for the anon part of the API (has to be created manually as this is the secondary GraphQL endpoint).
     */
    @Bean
    public WebGraphQlHandler anonWebGraphQlHandler(
            @Qualifier("anonExecutionGraphQlService") final ExecutionGraphQlService service,
            final ObjectProvider<WebGraphQlInterceptor> interceptorsProvider
    ) {
        return new GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration().webGraphQlHandler(service, interceptorsProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Execution GraphQL service for the auth part of the API (has to be created manually due to the {@link ConditionalOnMissingBean}
     * annotation in {@link GraphQlAutoConfiguration}).
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ExecutionGraphQlService authExecutionGraphQlService(
            final ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory,
            @Qualifier("authGraphQlSource") final GraphQlSource graphQlSource,
            final BatchLoaderRegistry batchLoaderRegistry
    ) {
        return new GraphQlAutoConfiguration(listableBeanFactory).executionGraphQlService(graphQlSource, batchLoaderRegistry);
    }

    /**
     * Execution GraphQL service for the auth part of the API (has to be created manually as this is the secondary GraphQL endpoint).
     */
    @Bean
    public ExecutionGraphQlService anonExecutionGraphQlService(
            final ListableBeanFactory listableBeanFactory,
            @Qualifier("anonGraphQlSource") final GraphQlSource graphQlSource,
            final BatchLoaderRegistry batchLoaderRegistry
    ) {
        return new GraphQlAutoConfiguration(listableBeanFactory).executionGraphQlService(graphQlSource, batchLoaderRegistry);
    }

    /**
     * Properties for configuration of the secondary anon GraphQL endpoint.
     * <p>
     * Wraps the existing {@link GraphQlProperties} so that a second variant can be given for the anon API, e.g.
     * "spring.graphql.path" defines the path of the auth API whereas "anon.graphql.path" teh one for the anon API.
     */
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "anon")
    public static final class AnonGraphQlProperties {

        private GraphQlProperties graphql;

        public GraphQlProperties getGraphql() {
            return graphql;
        }

        public void setGraphql(final GraphQlProperties graphql) {
            this.graphql = graphql;
        }
    }
}
```

So the basic idea is to provide another set of the core components for the second API endpoint (in my case the "anon" one). As Spring GraphQL uses a lot the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation, also a lot of components that would normally be auto created for the primary API (in my case the auth variant) need to be created by hand now.

I hope it get's obvious when looking at the source comments.

In the `application.properties` you can then define all known properties, especially a new schema location and path.

```
# Auth (default) GraphQL configuration
spring.graphql.path=/v1/graphql
spring.graphql.schema.locations=classpath:graphql/auth/**/
spring.graphql.schema.printer.enabled=true

# Anon GraphQL configuration
anon.graphql.path=/anon/v1/graphql
anon.graphql.schema.locations=classpath:graphql/anon/**/
anon.graphql.schema.printer.enabled=true
```