# How to stitch different shcemas to different endpoints in spring graphql?

Tags: spring, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471597/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-second-graphql-endpoint-in-a-spring-graphql-project). I want to have multiple schemas and expose them over separate endpoints. I tried the method suggested in the answer posted above, which is registering different `GraphQLSource` objects, but I am getting an issue that multiple `DataLoaders` are getting registered. I am guessing that is because I am trying to use `AnnotatedController` loaders i.e I am having annotated `@SchemaMapping` methods. When I try to not include the normal `GraphqlSource` only one of the schemas get registered, any help?

I tried following the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471597/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-second-graphql-endpoint-in-a-spring-graphql-project)